# Caching HTTP responses in a Tornado AsyncHTTPTestCase

Tags: python, tornado, nose

I have a test class extending `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase`, and I'm using Nose to run its test methods. Each of the test methods examines a response from a URL on the Tornado server under test. Some of these requests take several seconds to complete. Each request is tested in multiple methods.

I want to avoid making the same HTTP request twice during testing, since this slows down the tests significantly. What is the best way to ensure each of these requests is only made once?

Example:

```
class ServerTest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def test_endpoint(self):
        self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url('/'), self.stop)
        response = self.wait()
        self.assertTrue(response.code == 200)

    def test_endpoint_differently(self):
        self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url('/'), self.stop)
        response = self.wait()
        self.assertTrue(response.body != "")
```

Both of the above test methods request the `/` endpoint, which is slow. How can I have this request happen once (before the first test runs) and have the tests examine the cached responses?

I've gotten this working with a class variable like so:

```
class ServerTest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    responses = {}

    def setUp(self):
        if self.responses == {}:
            # do http request
            responses['/'] = result
```

but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this (maybe using Nose)? I've investigated the unittest `setUpClass` method, but since that method has to be a `@classmethod`, the http request utilities of the test case instance are not yet available at the time `setUpClass` runs.

Comment: Could you please provide any simplified example code?

Comment: @alecxe see example code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class implements my solution: https://gist.github.com/emmett9001/5785018

Looking into this a bit more made me realize that it doesn't make too much sense to frontload all of the requests as I had hoped. I implemented simple caching that ensures each request only happens once:

```
responses = {}

def cache_response(self, key, response):
    self.responses[key] = {}
    self.responses[key]['response'] = response
    self.responses[key]['time'] = dt.datetime.now()

def get_cached_url(self, path):
    if path not in self.responses.keys():
        self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url(path), self.stop)
        self.cache_response(path, self.wait(timeout=30))
    return self.responses[path]
```